# Using transaction in a loop in Yii

Tags: php, yii, transactions, yii1.x

I have an array of active records and want to change some field of them with a loop in this manner:

```
$error = false;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item->is_paid = self::PENDING;
    $error = $error || !$item->save();
}
return $error;
```

What I want to do is to change the `is_paid` property for all of this items. If on fails, roll back the others. How can I use transaction to solve this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By a brief look [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/14082-transaction-on-multiple-ar/page__view__findpost__p__152783), I was able to find the transaction management in yii, something like the following should work for you:

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $item->is_paid = self::PENDING;
        $item->save();
    }
    $transaction->commit();
    // actions to do on success (redirect, alert, etc.)
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
    // other actions to perform on fail (redirect, alert, etc.)
}
```